# Host freeware API over apt-get

Tags: apt, repository

I am new to Linux and Unix environment. I have built a Pro*C API for C++ and Oracle interaction, which much more easy to use than the conventional Pro*C technology.

> If you are using Pro*C then you might be aware of its pain. That, you need to write .pc file, then using Oracle precompiler, you need to compile the code to get .cpp file, then again compile it to get the .o (executable file). To make the process easy I created an API which provides the programmer with built-in classes and functions, so that he/she can implement it to boost the development of C++ and Oracle SQL.

Now, I want to host the API as a freeware so, that one can download the API using apt-get to their respective system. How can I host my file over apt-get?

Comment: You mean that you want to package your own deb package for the source code of the API?

Comment: @Braiam: I dint get that.. I am a novice. so.. what I need is, when you type `apt-get codbc` from linux command line, it install my package to the user system. Thats it!

Comment: Before you can create a new repository usable by `apt` system,  you need to build .deb-packages first. Both is not a trivial task and therefore to broad for a single question.

Comment: Is your software currently publicly available? If so, can you add a pointer to it? If your software depends on Oracle, then having an easy to install Debian package will be difficult, because Oracle is non-free, and as far as I know there are no Debian packages of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either get debian to distribute it -- not necessarily easy and certainly not quick, and you will need some more normal distribution point first -- or else host your own repository online and get your users to configure that into apt.

Almost nobody does that; google and dropbox come to mind.  Google I can understand, and dropbox and google both do it because they use proprietary parts and Debian *won't* distribute that. Methinks it will be more hassle than writing and maintaining a small C++ library.  A very good reason *not* to do this is it will turn away more users than it will attract.  If I went to download some unknown library like this and they wanted me to add a repository, I'd go look somewhere else, thanks.  What is the point of that?  I presume it's open source.  Why can't I just download a source tarball and build it?  If I'm a C++ programmer, I'm hardly likely to see that as a hassle.

In fact, on the contrary, I'd consider it *a convenience -- it's open source*.  `.deb` packages generally indicate a *binary build*; if you want the source you have to get it yourself seperately.  So you will have to maintain packages for multiple platforms (32-bit, 64-bit, ARM...) and maybe *multiple distos,* since I think not all debian derived distros use the same base.  This is not to mention non apt based linux distros (Arch, the entire Fedora family), and, since it sounds like your API is built on something already portable, non linux and even non-*nix systems.<sup>1</sup>  If you don't want to maintain binary packages and instead just have a source .deb, why bother?  I don't think *anybody* does that, because it's pointless and obviously so.

An online repo will be a hassle for you, and it is really a hassle for the user in the end too, because as mentioned, your average C++ programmer is not going to be in any way adverse to just working with a normal source tarball.  I presume this takes < 30 seconds to compile anyway.  Simple.  Easy.  Normal.  Done.

So I strongly encourage you to just host a page somewhere like github or [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/).  The later is free, widely known and respected, will give you automatic free publicity with its giant user base (most of which are other developers) and provides near full service web hosting. If you already have hosing somewhere, you can just create a static page for this. Setting up an apt repo, on the other hand, is something you will have to pay for on an ongoing basis because it will require a dedicated slice somewhere.

---

Note that you don't have to use a repository to create and distribute a `.deb` package, just your user's won't be able to use `apt-get`, they'll have to download it from your site.  You should have a page somewhere describing the product, etc., even if you host a repo as well.

<sup>1</sup> In essence, you'd be taking what sounds like a package that could be used anywhere -- windows, OSX, anywhere with Oracle and a C++ compiler -- and packaging it in a completely non-portable and restrictive way so only users of debian based systems can access it.  Kind of bass-ackward.

Comment: Actually, creating Debian packaging for a package is very useful. Just distributing binaries is much less so, because they probably won't install on ones system. Lots of people create bunches of binary debs, but I really think just the packaging information is what is important because if you have that, you can build the software yourself. If the build system and/or dependencies are complicated, this can save a lot of time.

Comment: @FaheemMitha : Fair enough -- but much better to use `autoconf` for resolving dependencies, although that limits portability too.  **CMake** is a good option.  Although in this case, assuming the dependencies are few and obvious (Oracle and C++), you can **just state the obvious.**  Anyone who can't build a small, portable C++ library competently can't possibly use the API anyway: there's no point in dumbing things down too much.  No one will care, and you are more likely to confuse people than anything else.

Comment: Yes, my comment was a general one. I'm not sure how useful a Debian package would be in this specific context.

Comment: @FaheemMitha : Of course, not using a repository doesn't mean you can't distribute a `.deb.`.  I'll add a small note about this.